# webView does not work for osx

Tags: macos, webview, crash

I try to make a webview that shows the page of google but if I run my program It just crashes.
my code in .h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> 

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (weak) IBOutlet WebView *myWebView; //here I want to show google.com

@end
```

my code in .m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize myWebView;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
[self loadWeb];
}

-(void)loadWeb {
[[webv mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:          @"http://www.google.de"]]]; // here I want to load the page
}


@end
```

The issue always says:
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return NSApplicationMain(argc, (const char **)argv); //green marked: Thread 1: signal SIGABRT 
}

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
#import <WebKit/WebView.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

the webview instance is an IBOutlet , so you should call it from awakeFromNib , something like this ,

-(void)awakeFromNib{
   [ self loadWeb];
}